# Can Stage Manager on iPadOS 16 finally force all app into landscape mode?

Tags: apple-silicon, stage-manager

iPadOS 15 can force apps into landscape mode, but indeed most portrait app will still run in full screen portrait mode, whether an portrait app can run in landscape mode depends on the app.

Can iPadOS 16 on M1 iPads finally force all apps into landscape mode and you will never need to rotate iPad for a portrait app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't force it into landscape but displays them properly so you don't have to rotate - it displays them in portrait mode in landscape like this image: [image: ipad landscape portrait iOS app]

Also, it's available on non-M1 iPads as well up to the 2018 iPad Pro.